# Navigate to a specific page using the notifications in UWP app

Tags: javascript, uwp

I'm writing a UWP app (Javascript), and I have a ScheduledToastNotification to act as an alarm. The notification appears on time, but when I click on the notification (no buttons, just on the notification in general), the app doesn't launch correctly, it launches into the root page. Also, I am not able to access the params I am passing into the app using the notification. The code is attached below:

```
var Notifications = Windows.UI.Notifications;
var currentTime = new Date();
var seconds = 60;
var dueTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + seconds * 60 * 1000);
var idNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000);  // Generates a unique ID number for the notification.

// Set up the notification text.
var toastXml = Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.getTemplateContent(Notifications.ToastTemplateType.toastText02);
var strings = toastXml.getElementsByTagName("text");
strings[0].appendChild(toastXml.createTextNode(This is a scheduled toast notification));
strings[1].appendChild(toastXml.createTextNode("Received: " + dueTime.toLocaleTimeString()));



var toastNode = toastXml.selectSingleNode("/toast");
toastNode.setAttribute("duration", "long");
var audio = toastXml.createElement("audio");

audio.setAttribute("src", "ms-winsoundevent:Notification.IM");
toastXml.selectSingleNode("/toast").setAttribute("launch", '{"type":"details","contentId":"112234","contentType":"Music"}');

// Create the toast notification object.
var toast = new Notifications.ScheduledToastNotification(toastXml, dueTime);
toast.id = "Toast" + idNumber;

// Add to the schedule.
Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.createToastNotifier().addToSchedule(toast);
```

How do I get the app to navigate to correct route? Which event do I listen to perform this and watch for the params I have passed.

Comment: The documentation for same is either non-existent or very vague.

Comment: Have your processed `onactive` method?

Comment: Could you give a code snippet as an example?

Comment: Sure, please refer this [line](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/SharedContent/js/js/default.js#L15) in the code sample.

Comment: This seems to be very old and the WinJS namespace is not available anymore. I have tried using Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApllication.addEventListener('activated', cb()). But this also does not seem to work. Finally I put it inside an timeout and called cb() directly, only that seems to work. Could you shed some light on what I am doing wrong ?